# Which test to use on partially overlapping groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have data in 4 categories, but they are not completely independent. To explain the data: I have looked at 40 Intelligent Tutoring Systems (ITSs) and determined which approach they use (model tracing, constraints, example tracing or tests) and the frequency of aspects they diagnosed.

I'll provide a subset of the data:

**Model tracing tutors**     23

- Correctness            23
- Buggy rules            14
- Type of error          12
- Difference             2
- Preference             2

**Constraint-based tutors**          11

- Correctness            11
- Type of error          8
- Buggy rules            5
- Preference             3

When looking at the data, it seems that the groups are different. For example, that model tracing ITSs are more likely to diagnose buggy rules than constraint-based ITSs. I'm not sure which test to use to determine whether this difference is significant.

My problem is that the categories partially overlap, there are 5 ITSs that are in both the model tracing and constraints group. Another problem is that the categories do not all have the same aspects, e.g. the constraint-based tutors do not diagnose Difference.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I have a somehow similar question with no answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350754/dealing-with-multiple-cases-per-subject